# how to merge multiple excel files into one

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have tried searching this on google but could get the answer for my problem.
I am trying to merge multiple excel files into single one using below code.
But it is giving me error like below (no additional info in innerexception) at sheet.Copy command.

```
Unable to get the Copy property of the Worksheet class
```

Code...

```
private void MergeXlsxFiles(string destXlsxFileName, params string[] sourceXlsxFileNames)
        {
            Application excelApp = null;
            Workbook destWorkBook = null;
            var temppathForTarget = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() , Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls");

            if (File.Exists(temppathForTarget))
                File.Delete(temppathForTarget);

            try
            {
                excelApp = new Application
                {
                    DisplayAlerts = false,
                    SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3
                };
                destWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
                destWorkBook.SaveAs(temppathForTarget);


                foreach (var sourceXlsxFile in sourceXlsxFileNames)
                {
                    var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), sourceXlsxFile);
                    var sourceWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);

                    foreach (Worksheet ws in sourceWorkBook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        var wSheet = destWorkBook.Worksheets[destWorkBook.Worksheets.Count];
                        ws.Copy(wSheet);
                        destWorkBook.Worksheets[destWorkBook.Worksheets.Count].Name =
                            ws.Name; 
                    }
                    sourceWorkBook.Close(XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges);
                }
                destWorkBook.Sheets[1].Delete();
                destWorkBook.SaveAs(destXlsxFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (destWorkBook != null)
                    destWorkBook.Close(XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges);
                if (excelApp != null)
                    excelApp.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong with this code.

I am referring Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll from GAC with version 15.0.0.0 and I have MSOffice 2013 installed on my machine.

Comment: Possibly due to `in sourceWorkBook.Sheets` and/or `destWorkBook.Sheets`. `Sheets` are not the same things as `Worksheets`. They can be, but they can also be other kinds of sheets, such as chart sheets. Try `in sourceWorkbook.Worksheets` and destWorkBook.Worksheets`?

Comment: I tried with Worksheets but still the same error. I updated my question with these changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when I test the code in the question, it runs into problems with data typing. Excel is "picky" about data typing - it's often necessary to explicitly cast a type. The following `foreach` works for me: Notice the `(Excel.Worksheet)` casts. With those I ran into no problems with the `Copy` (or the `Name`) method (property).

I also ran into "oddities" assigning sheet names. The logic used in the code in the question is not clear, so on the assumption the new sheets should be added after the default three empty sheets, I altered `ws.Copy` to put them at the end.

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in sourceWorkBook.Worksheets)
{
    var wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) destWorkBook.Worksheets[destWorkBook.Worksheets.Count];
    ws.Copy(missing, wSheet);
    Excel.Worksheet wNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)destWorkBook.Worksheets[destWorkBook.Worksheets.Count];
    wNewSheet.Name = "New" + ws.Name; 
}
```

Comment: That works for me. Thanks a lot... One more thing.... My old code also work when my excel files extension is .xlsx not with .xls

Comment: When using the "interop" - the code is interacting with the Excel application - the file format/extension doesn't matter. Excel interacts with all file types it can open the same way. What matters with the "interop" is the version of Excel - that determines what functionality is available. If code is working with the Open XML file format directly (Open XML SDK, for instance) then the file format makes a difference.